# How to fix a cast iron bench

Tags: repair, furniture, bench

How can I fix a cast iron wood bench from rim rack from side to side?

I have tightened all screws for each slat of wood including brackets underneath to secure the wood to the iron, but I cannot sit on it as it sways.

Thanks, C.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the bench? (just add a link to a sharing site like imgur.com and someone with enough rep will add it for you).  Any solution will depend entirely on the design of the bench.

Answer (score 2):

- repair worn fittings / material
- make oversize holes and use oversize bolts
- install cross-bracing
- ...